# How to remove event listener for react-native-tts async function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have tried the following code to remove event listener in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.subscription = Tts.addEventListener('tts-finish', this._startRecognition.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Tts.speak('Welcome to Hello World');
  }

  _startRecognition() {
    console.log('==================== recognizing text that was spoken ====================');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Tts.removeEventListener('tts-finish');
  }
}
```

When I open this component again, it will fire up the `_startRecognition` method. Is there an elegant way to removing event listener. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Tts.speak('Welcome to Hello World');
    Tts.addEventListener('tts-finish', this._startRecognition)
  }

  _startRecognition() {
    console.log('==================== recognizing text that was spoken ====================');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Tts.removeEventListener('tts-finish', this._startRecognition);
  }
}
```